# Ruby - get key and value from array of hashes easily

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

Have an array of single pair hashes, like this:

```
arguments = [{:name=>"ABCD"},{:title=>"Awesome"},{:number=>4}]
```

I need to loop through and pull each one off as a key and value. Right now, I'm doing this:

```
def methodname(*arguments, &block)
  arguments.each do |arg|
    arg.each do |key, value|
      # use my key and value
    end
  end
  # use the &block here in awesome ways
end
```

Ick. Gotta be a better way, so I'm asking if someone knows it. I've searched and can't seem to find this particular question on StackOverflow, but let me know if it's out there.

EDIT: Added context to the code example.

Comment: That… actually doesn't look that bad to me. You're iterating over an array, which takes a line, and you're iterating over each key-value pair in the hash, which takes a line. That's about as clean and simple as it gets.

Comment: I suspect he wants to avoid "iterating over each key-value pair" since there is only ever going to be *one* key-value pair.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: ahh, good call. Gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If arguments are expected to be unique...

```
arguments.inject({},:merge).each { ... }
```

FWIW - if you can change this data structure, it might be a good idea to do so.  This data is better represented in a single hash.

You can also define your method differently and avoid the problem altogether.

```
irb(main):011:0> def foo(kwargs={},&block)
irb(main):012:1>    pp kwargs
irb(main):013:1> end
irb(main):025:0> foo(:biz=>1,:baz=>2)
{:biz=>1, :baz=>2}
=> nil
```

Comment: I agree with changing the data structure. It's what I am getting with this:

def methodname(*arguments, &block)
   # stuff
end

Excuse the idiotic formatting...you get the point.

Comment: BTW: you can write `arguments.inject({}, :merge)` instead. Or just `arguments.inject(:merge)` if you are sure that there will always be at least one condition.

Comment: @dfb I get syntax error, unexpected tPOW, expecting ')'. Note this is RubyMotion...that probably complicates things a bit.

Comment: @JamonHolmgren - My mistake.  You can do `methodname(kwargs={},&block)` and then pass in key-value pairs. kwargs will contain the input as a hash

Comment: I'd have to call it with methodname { name: "ABCD", title: "yo" } do ? I'd prefer not to have to pass in a hash.

Comment: @JamonHolmgren - not sure what you're asking, you don't need to pass in a hash explictly, but see my edits

Comment: @dfb Didn't realize I could do that. Much, much better! Thank you.

Comment: @dfb can you edit your answer to show the redefined method? That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Since this isn't a common idiom, you're not gonna find a really clean solution out there. Regardless, here's a decent shot at it:

```
arguments.map(&:first).each do |key, value|
    # use key and value for something
end
```

This solution takes advantage of the fact that `Hash`, as an `Enumerable`, has a `first` method that returns the first result it would yield on iteration, so `{:foo => :bar}.first == [:foo, :bar]`. Map that through all the hashes and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, this was a good answer, but redefining the method ended up being a better solution.

Comment: @JamonHolmgren: ahh, seeing the context, yup, that's definitely the better answer. Glad it's all sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
arguments.each do |arg|
  (key, value), = *arg
  # use my key and value
end
```

I guess whether or not you consider this to be "a better way" mostly depends on whether your teammates understand how assignment works in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, this looks reasonable. Looking through the rest of the answers for the most elegant solution.

Comment: BTW: that trailing comma is easy to miss, maybe introducing a dummy variable would be more readable: `(key, value), _ = *arg`. I'm on the fence about this.